# EF6: Single relationship table for multiple related entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a EF Model with many entities, like Nodes, Attributes, Tags, etc.

There is also an "Alias" entity, and pretty much every other entity else can have a many-to-many relationship with Aliases.  One of the undesired things about this is the number of tables that are created to track these relationships (eg. NodeAlias, AttributeAlias, etc.).

Are there any design alternatives that could map an Alias to all of the other entities in a single table?  I was thinking maybe something along these lines if it's possible:

```
+---------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| AliasId | NodeId | AttributeId |   TagId   |
+---------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|       1 |      1 |           2 |         3 |
+---------+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my solution to provide many-to-many relationships between aliases and every other entity.

I intentionally posted this as a separate answer so that my previous answer can also remain here if anyone would need it.

**Step #1:** I created extension methods for getting and setting property values using reflection in a convenient way:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TResult GetPropertyValue<TResult>(this object entity, string propertyName)
    {
        object propertyValue = entity?.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(entity);

        try
        {
            return (TResult)propertyValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }
    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue(this object entity, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        entity?.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.SetValue(entity, value);
    }
}
```

**Step #2:** I updated the models to provide many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    [Key]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }
}

public class Alias
{
    [Key]
    public int AliasId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }
}

public class AliasMapping
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Alias")]
    public int AliasId { get; set; }

    public Alias Alias { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Node")]
    public int? NodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Node { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Attribute")]
    public int? AttributeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tag")]
    public int? TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

**Step #3:** Due to relationship changes the `MyDbContext` could have been simplified as the `[ForeignKey]` data annotations are enough.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }
}
```

**Step #4:** I also updated the extension methods so that you can create and remove alias mappings.

```
public static class AliasExtensions
{
    public static void CreateMapping(this MyDbContext context, object entity, Alias alias)
    {
        if (entity == null || alias == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string mappingEntityPropertyName = entity.GetType().Name;
        string entityKeyPropertyName = String.Concat(mappingEntityPropertyName, "Id");
        int entityId = entity.GetPropertyValue<int>(entityKeyPropertyName);

        AliasMapping[] mappings =
            context
                .AliasMappings
                .Where(mapping => mapping.AliasId == alias.AliasId)
                .ToArray();

        if (mappings.Any(mapping => mapping.GetPropertyValue<int?>(entityKeyPropertyName) == entityId))
        {
            // We already have the mapping between the specified entity and alias.
            return;
        }

        bool usableMappingExists = true;
        var usableMapping = mappings.FirstOrDefault(mapping => mapping.GetPropertyValue<int?>(entityKeyPropertyName) == null);

        if (usableMapping == null)
        {
            usableMappingExists = false;
            usableMapping = new AliasMapping()
            {
                Alias = alias
            };
        }

        usableMapping.SetPropertyValue(mappingEntityPropertyName, entity);
        usableMapping.SetPropertyValue(entityKeyPropertyName, entityId);

        if (!usableMappingExists)
        {
            context.AliasMappings.Add(usableMapping);
        }

        // This step is required here, I think due to using reflection.
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void RemoveMapping(this MyDbContext context, object entity, Alias alias)
    {
        if (entity == null || alias == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string mappingEntityPropertyName = entity.GetType().Name;
        string entityKeyPropertyName = String.Concat(mappingEntityPropertyName, "Id");
        int entityId = entity.GetPropertyValue<int>(entityKeyPropertyName);

        AliasMapping[] mappings =
            context
                .AliasMappings
                .Where(mapping => mapping.AliasId == alias.AliasId)
                .ToArray();

        AliasMapping currentMapping = mappings.FirstOrDefault(mapping => mapping.GetPropertyValue<int?>(entityKeyPropertyName) == entityId);

        if (currentMapping == null)
        {
            // There is no mapping between the specified entity and alias.
            return;
        }

        currentMapping.SetPropertyValue(mappingEntityPropertyName, null);
        currentMapping.SetPropertyValue(entityKeyPropertyName, null);

        // This step is required here, I think due to using reflection.
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Step #5:** Updated the console app steps to align it with the changes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Consider specify the appropriate database initializer!
        // I use DropCreateDatabaseAlways<> strategy only for this example.
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());

        var aliases =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 9)
                .Select(index => new Alias() { Name = String.Format("Alias{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var attributes =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Attribute() { Name = String.Format("Attribute{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var nodes =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Node() { Name = String.Format("Node{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var tags =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Tag() { Name = String.Format("Tag{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            context.Aliases.AddRange(aliases);
            context.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
            context.Attributes.AddRange(attributes);
            context.Tags.AddRange(tags);

            // Always save changes after adding an entity but before trying to create a mapping.
            context.SaveChanges();

            // One Alias To Many Entities
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[0], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[1], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[2], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[3], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(attributes[0], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(attributes[1], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(attributes[2], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(tags[0], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(tags[1], aliases[0]);

            // One Entity To Many Aliases
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[4], aliases[0]);
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[4], aliases[1]);
            context.CreateMapping(nodes[4], aliases[2]);
            context.CreateMapping(attributes[3], aliases[1]);
            context.CreateMapping(attributes[3], aliases[3]);
            context.CreateMapping(tags[2], aliases[2]);
            context.CreateMapping(tags[2], aliases[3]);

            // Remove mapping
            context.RemoveMapping(nodes[4], aliases[0]);

            // Not really needed here as both 'CreateMapping' and 'RemoveMapping' save the changes
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . .");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

**Please note:** `RemoveMapping()` will not delete an `AliasMapping` even if no entity is associated with it! But `CreateMapping()` will make use of it later if needed. E.g. look at the screenshot below and check `AliasMapping` where `Id` = 5.

Screenshot about the execution result:

[image: AliasMapping]

Answer (score 0):

You were talking about many-to-many relationship but reading your post I think it is more likely a "special one-to-many" relationship, actually "combined multiple one-to-one" relationship as I see that an `Alias` can be mapped to a single `Node` AND/OR to a single `Attribute` AND/OR to a single `Tag`.

I think I found a solution for this case.

If it's not the case and an `Alias` can be mapped to multiple `Node` AND/OR to multiple `Attribute` AND/OR to multiple `Tag` then I think this solution below needs only a small change. :)

Step #1 - These are my example models

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual AliasMapping AliasMapping { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual AliasMapping AliasMapping { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual AliasMapping AliasMapping { get; set; }
}

public class Alias
{
    [Key]
    public int AliasId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual AliasMapping AliasMapping { get; set; }
}
```

Step #2 - Creating the custom mapping table

```
public class AliasMapping
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Alias")]
    public int AliasId { get; set; }

    public Alias Alias { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Node")]
    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Node { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Attribute")]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tag")]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Step #3 - Creating the DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AliasMapping> AliasMappings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<AliasMapping>()
            .HasOptional(mapping => mapping.Attribute)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(attribute => attribute.AliasMapping)
            .Map(config => config.MapKey("AliasId"));

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<AliasMapping>()
            .HasOptional(mapping => mapping.Node)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(node => node.AliasMapping)
            .Map(config => config.MapKey("AliasId"));

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<AliasMapping>()
            .HasOptional(mapping => mapping.Tag)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(tag => tag.AliasMapping)
            .Map(config => config.MapKey("AliasId"));
    }
}
```

Step #4 - Creating extension method so that creating a relationship will be easy

```
public static class AliasExtensions
{
    public static void CreateMapping<TEntity>(this MyDbContext context, TEntity entity, Alias alias)
    {
        string mappingEntityPropertyName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        string entityKeyPropertyName = String.Concat(mappingEntityPropertyName, "Id");

        bool entityExists = true;
        var mapping = context.AliasMappings.Find(alias.AliasId);

        if (mapping == null)
        {
            entityExists = false;
            mapping = new AliasMapping()
            {
                Alias = alias
            };
        }

        typeof(AliasMapping)
            .GetProperty(mappingEntityPropertyName)
            .SetValue(mapping, entity);

        typeof(AliasMapping)
            .GetProperty(entityKeyPropertyName)
            .SetValue(mapping, typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity));

        if (!entityExists)
        {
            context.AliasMappings.Add(mapping);
        }
    }
}
```

Step #5 - Created a console app to see this working

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());

        var aliases =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 9)
                .Select(index => new Alias() { Name = String.Format("Alias{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var attributes =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Attribute() { Name = String.Format("Attribute{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var nodes =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Node() { Name = String.Format("Node{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        var tags =
            Enumerable
                .Range(1, 5)
                .Select(index => new Tag() { Name = String.Format("Tag{0:00}", index) })
                .ToList();

        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            context.Aliases.AddRange(aliases);
            context.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
            context.Attributes.AddRange(attributes);
            context.Tags.AddRange(tags);

            context.SaveChanges();

            // Associate aliases to attributes
            attributes.ForEach(attribute =>
            {
                var usableAliases = aliases.Where(alias => alias.AliasMapping?.Attribute == null).ToList();
                var selectedAlias = usableAliases[rnd.Next(usableAliases.Count)];
                context.CreateMapping(attribute, selectedAlias);
            });

            // Associate aliases to nodes
            nodes.ForEach(node =>
            {
                var usableAliases = aliases.Where(alias => alias.AliasMapping?.Node == null).ToList();
                var selectedAlias = usableAliases[rnd.Next(usableAliases.Count)];
                context.CreateMapping(node, selectedAlias);
            });

            // Associate aliases to tags
            tags.ForEach(tag =>
            {
                var usableAliases = aliases.Where(alias => alias.AliasMapping?.Tag == null).ToList();
                var selectedAlias = usableAliases[rnd.Next(usableAliases.Count)];
                context.CreateMapping(tag, selectedAlias);
            });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . .");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for that!  I have one question about the solution:
What is a Node needed a collection of Aliases, instead of just 0 or 1?  Would there be a slick way of doing that, even if it meant a separate record in the Aliases table?

Comment: @blgrnboy I added a new answer which provides you the many-to-many relationship between aliases and every other entities. Check it out! ;)